# Ajax script not changing button text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made a comment system in which i am inserting comments in my db through Ajax. Problem is, It adds the comments in db correctly but does not work with the success code for `submit`. Any suggestions please.

**Form**

```
 <h4>Add your Review:</h4>
  <?php
  if(isset($_SESSION["login_email"]) && !empty($_SESSION["login_email"]))
          {
        $email=$_SESSION['login_email'];
          ?>
        <div id="addCommentContainer">
        <form id="addCommentForm" method="post" action="">
         <div>
        <label for="body">Review</label>
         <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
         <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email?>" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
             <?php
           }
     else{
       echo "Login to add review!";
        }
        ?>
 </div>
```

**script.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var working = false;
        $('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            if(working) return false;
            working = true;
            $('#submit').val('Working..');
            $('span.error').remove();

           $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
          //This code isn't working 
                working = false;
                $('#submit').val('Submit');

                if(msg.status){
            $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
                    $('#body').val('');
                }
                else {
                $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
                $('label[for='+k+']').append('<span class="error">'+v+'</span>');
                    });
                }
            },'json');

        });

    });
```

**submit.php**

```
 <?php

        // Error reporting:
        error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

        include "db/db.php";
        include "comment.class.php";

        /*
        /   This array is going to be populated with either
        /   the data that was sent to the script, or the
        /   error messages.
        /*/

        $arr = array();

        $validates = Comment::validate($arr);

        if($validates)
        {
            /* Everything is OK, insert to database: */

            mysqli_query($con," INSERT INTO comments(email,body,product_id)
                            VALUES (
                                '".$arr['email']."',
                                 '".$arr['body']."',
                                 '".$arr['productid']."'
                            )");


            $arr['dt'] = date('r',time());
            $arr['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($con);

            /*
            /   The data in $arr is escaped for the mysql query,
            /   but we need the unescaped variables, so we apply,
            /   stripslashes to all the elements in the array:
            /*/

            $arr = array_map('stripslashes',$arr);

            $insertedComment = new Comment($arr);


            /* Outputting the markup of the just-inserted comment: */

            echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'html'=>$insertedComment->markup()));

        }
        else
        {
            /* Outputtng the error messages */
            echo '{"status":0,"errors":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried another method where, instead of keeping `input` tag for the button, keep a `button` tag and check if the code works? But here `$('#submit').val();` would change to `$('#submit').html()` or `$('#submit').text()`

Comment: @dvenkatsagar `$('#submit').html('Submit')` also does not work

Comment: Even if you change the `input` tag to `button` tag?

Comment: What the issue are you getting ?

Comment: @AliKhanusiya problem is it inserts the values in db succesfully but it does not change the button value to submit from working and code after that

Comment: Well that is weird....

Comment: what is the php code returning? Is it in proper JSON?

Comment: show the contents of `submit.php`

Comment: @CodeGodie i have updated my question

Comment: @tabia I dont see `submit.php`

Comment: @CodeGodie have a look please.

Comment: @CodeGodie i debugged my script but it doesnot move the debugger afte the commented line in `script.js`

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by _" it doesnot move the debugger"_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101713/discussion-between-tabia-and-codegodie).

Answer (score 0):

Make your submit button disable until you do not get response from server.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $('#submit').prop("disabled", true);

        $('span.error').remove();

        $.ajax({
            url: "submit.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#addCommentForm').serialize()
            success: function(result) {

                $('#submit').prop("disabled", true);


                if (msg.status) {
                    $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
                    $('#body').val('');
                } else {
                    $.each(msg.errors, function(k, v) {
                        $('label[for=' + k + ']').append('<span class="error">' + v + '</span>');
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

add `.done`, `.fail`, `.always` after your `.post()` and you will see errors. In the sample code below I am printing to the console. It seems like the issue is that you are requiring that your data returned is in `JSON` format, but you are not sending it in JSON. Convert your data to JSON, then send it:

```
 $.post('submit.php', $(this).serialize(), function (msg) {
     working = false;
     $('#submit').val('Submit');
     if (msg.status) {
         $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
         $('#body').val('');
     } else {
         $.each(msg.errors, function (k, v) {
              $('label[for=' + k + ']').append('<span class="error">' + v + '</span>');
         });
     }

 }, 'json').done(function () {
     alert("second success");
 }).fail(function (a,b,c) {
     console.log(a);
     console.log(b);
     console.log(c);
 }).always(function () {
     alert("finished");
 });
```

UPDATE:

Make sure your `submit.php` is returning JSON like this:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Comment: it does not helped me

Comment: show the contents of your `submit.php` so we can see whats going on